# Spark self join (hierarchy)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hierarchical

let's assume we have table "hier" (parent_id bigint, child_id bigint)

The query i need to build looks like

```
Select * from hier h1
         join hier h2 on h1.parent_id = h2.child_id
         join hier h3 on h2.parent_id = h3.child_id
         join hier h4 on h3.parent_id = h4.child_id
```

The depth is always the same, the query is static

Is there a way to avoid scaning hier table  (it's quite big in my case) for four times?

i'm limited to pyspark for realization

Comment: you can persist hier table, before executing your code. its best practice to persist a table if your gonna be using it multiple times.

Comment: You can persist that table but its too big and will take too much memory. I would let it scan 4 times

Comment: Its a hard one for spark. Did u try the explain?

Answer (score 1):

Hierarchical data or recursive queries are challenging topic in pyspark. By selecting only two columns it helps by a lot the query execution. I would also suggest the following:

- Cache hier: Given you will apply lots of operations down the line and there're 4 times joins.
- Checkpoint before the 3rd and 4th join: Read/Write your data into a temporary location and you can cut down the execution plan.
- Use CTE (common table expressions) with Spark SQL instead. This can be more efficient than using the dataframes API for recurisive queries. Important: Spark does NOT accept Recursive CTE, the CTE will help you to make your code neat and probably more performant given the step by step nature.